# what is difference between db.collection.find() and db.collection.aggregation()

Tags: mongodb-query

I am new Mongodb. I am trying to figure out the difference between db.collection.find() and db.collection.aggregation()

When i executing the both commands both are yielding the same result.

More insight please...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregation is a command that is used to, well, aggregate different processors of data, whether they are filters, groupings, etc. It's real use is to take multiple operations that you specify for data processing, then optimize them so that it returns your result of all filters/groups/whatever in the most efficient way possible.

However, as you said, by passing nothing, you are just going to receive data as you would see in find(). The reason this is the case is because to the aggregation framework, it is seeing that there are no filters/groupings/queries to abide by, and therefore decides that you want to return all the data. However it is still inefficient to use Aggregation() over Find() because you are still doing some extra things that give a bit of a performance hit.

More information about aggregations and aggregation pipelines can be found here: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking unless you need a specific aggregation operator it's best to use `find` instead, it performs better.

Now why is the aggregation framework performance "worse"? it's simple. it just does "more".

Any pipeline stage needs aggregation to fetch the BSON for the document then convert them to internal objects in the pipeline for processing - then at the end of the pipeline they are converted back to `BSON` and sent to the client.

This, especially for large queries, has a very significant overhead compared to a `find` where the `BSON` is just sent back to the client.

Because of this, if you could execute your aggregation as a `find` query, you should.

There are more actual differences, like the query planner used for each. however in theory those things should not behave too differently.